# What mail applications use crypto?

Tags: encryption, email, pgp, gmail

I just read that everyone in the world can ready my mails (if intercepted in traffic by eavesdropping?). Also, it reads that current versions (book's from 2004 so I assume that new versions adopt encryption policies) of Outlook and Eudora have built-in crypto. Is it sufficient or should I use PGP on every mail I send? How about my favorite gmail? Does it include end-to-end encryption? If so, is it sufficient?

Sorry for being a newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail does not include native encryption features that can be used via webmail.  Broadly speaking, webmail services that provide encryption are doomed to failure, and this for a very simple reason: the only encryption that you can trust is end-to-end i.e. from your machine to your correspondent's machine.

You can achieve this by installing a plugin for email encryption on your mailclient.  The most used standard is probably OpenPGP, which is implemented on the open source and free software GnuPG (cross-platform) or GPG4Win (for Windows).  However, your correspondent must do the same.  Note that in this way you can encrypt/decrypt messages no matter the email service you use, provided that it gives you access to email via POP or IMAP and not only webmail.

Comment: Google does have an end to end tool in the Making. See here: https://github.com/google/end-to-end/wiki http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.in/2014/12/an-update-to-end-to-end.html http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.in/2014/06/making-end-to-end-encryption-easier-to.html

Comment: True, but in this case you might as well install an OpenPGP tool, which works with all email providers.

Comment: I recommend a OpenPGP plugin for Firefox / Chrome called [Mailvelope](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mailvelope/kajibbejlbohfaggdiogboambcijhkke?hl=en). You and the people you communicate with have to do manual key management, but the UI is pretty slick and works right in your browser with any of the major webmail providers.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed use an end to end cryptographic encryption tool with Gmail. But be warned that it is still in test stage so there is a chance it is still buggy. Or you could always wait for the next version (which I think will be 4 to 6 months ahead) by which point it will be released as a stable extension (hopefully!)

Another caveat is that it is a Chrome only extension so you'd have to use Chrome to access gmail.

Finally, it doesn't come with mobile support yet.

See here:

https://github.com/google/end-to-end/wiki

http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.in/2014/12/an-update-to-end-to-end.html

http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.in/2014/06/making-end-to-end-encryption-easier-to.html

Answer (score 0):

While You can setup encrypted emailing this is not on by default.
It is not trivial to do so and requires action from both sender and receiver

Email is essentially a clear text protocol and since you do not host it yourself you have no clue about how it's transmitted between sender / receiver. 
It's better to assume that whatever you write as an email can be read by everyone than try protecting against it since the protection (encryption) requires non-trivial setups. Either through SSL certificates or through a PKI system (like pgp).

Answer (score 0):

protonmail looks promising
https://protonmail.ch/
but (a word of caution) done by smart people who are not cryptographers by trade or training.